# Prime factorization over the Eisenstein integers $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$

Tags: complex, number-theory, factorization, prime-numbers

I am trying to write a function `f[a_,b_]` which takes in two integers $a,b$ and returns the unique factorization of $a+be^{2\pi i/3}$ into the primes belonging to $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i/3}]$.

In other words, `f` gives the factorization of $a+be^{2\pi i /3}$ into Eisenstein primes.

**Useful facts.** The Eisenstein primes have the following possible forms:

- $1-e^{2\pi i/3}$
- Primes in $\mathbb{Z}$ congruent to $2 \pmod 3$
- The Eisenstein integers $g,\bar{g}$ such that $g \bar{g} = q$, where $q \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$

Here, I denote $\bar{z}$ to mean $(a+bB)(a+bB^2)$. Also, Eisenstein integers are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2 \pi i/3}]$.

**Desired output.** I am trying to create `f` to function similar to `FactorInteger`. It would output a list of pairs `{x,y}` for each Eisenstein prime $x$ dividing $v=a+be^{2\pi i/3}$, with $y$ being the highest power of $x$ dividing $v$.

**Some convention.** I denote `B=1-E^(2Pi*i/3)`, and I want `f` to use this instead of `E^(2Pi*I/3)`.

**Example output.** Because $24-36B=B^2*2^2*(5+2B)$, we have `f[24,-36] = {  {B,2} , {2,2} , {5+2B,1} }`.

**My 'work'.** There was stuff here, but I realized I was forgetting something. Currently working on the program in question.

Comment: I am not sure what's your exact difficulty. So you already have an "conceptual algorithm" in mind, and just unable to articulate it in Mathematica language? For example, do you know how to handle the hard case of factor a prime $p\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$?

Comment: @pisco Yes. As to factoring $p$, I know how to brute-force it. I would need some time to think of a better method to factor $p$.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41440/4346

Comment: I spent a chunk of yesterday trying to figure out how one might do this. I should have just waited for @ChipHurst to comment...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau you and I both. I finished a program yesterday that factors Eisenstein integers, but not as quickly as I would like. Does the post which ChipHurst linked also factor non-integer Eisenstein integers? I have not run it myself.

Comment: I think the response I put into that 2014 thread will handle the rational primes of the form 3n+1 with reasonable efficiency.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau but does it factor non-rational Eisenstein integers?

Comment: That is handled by factoring the norm via FactorInteger, then using division over Z[w] to get divisors of a+b*w (as opposed to divisors of a+b*w^2).